# How to prove $Spec A_1\times Spec A_2=Spec ( A_1\otimes A_2)$ by a direct way?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, category-theory, fibre-product

Let $R$ is a commutative ring with unit. Consider two $R$-algebra $A_1$ and $A_2$, namely, two unit commutative rings with morphisms $\phi_1: R\to A_1$ and $\phi_2:R\to A_2$. Consider any a prime ideal $\mathfrak p\in \mathrm{Spec}(A_1\otimes_R A_2)$. Let $\mathfrak p_1$ is the set that consists of all elements $a$ such that $a\otimes 1\in \mathfrak p$, and $\mathfrak p_2$ is the set consists of all elements $b$ such that $1\otimes b\in \mathfrak p$. It is easy to prove $\mathfrak p_1\in \mathrm{Spec}A_1$ and $\mathfrak p_2\in \mathrm{Spec} A_2$. Then, my question is, does exist two prime ideal $\mathfrak p,\overline{\mathfrak p}$, will give the same $\mathfrak p_1$ and $\mathfrak p_2$? How to prove? Thanks!

OK, in fact, my question is to find a non-standrad but more direct method to prove $\mathrm{Spec}\,A_1\times_{\mathrm{Spec}\,R}\mathrm{Spec}\,A_2\simeq \mathrm{Spec}\,\big(A_1\otimes_R A_2\big)$.

Comment: Your question is not the same as the summary of your question at the bottom, because the underlying topological space of the product of two schemes (or even varieties) is not the same as the product of the underlying topological spaces of the schemes.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying set of $\mathrm{Spec}(A_1)\times_{\mathrm{Spec}(R)} \mathrm{Spec}(A_2)$ is not the cartesian product of $\mathrm{Spec}(A_1)$ and $\mathrm{Spec}(A_2)$: think for example about the case $R=k$, $A_1=A_2=k[x]$. For every irreducible affine plane curve, there's a point in $\mathrm{Spec}(A_1) \times_{\mathrm{Spec}(R)}\mathrm{Spec}(A_2)\cong \Bbb A^2_k$, but such points don't correspond to a pair of points in $|\Bbb A^1_k| \times |\Bbb A^1_k|$. But it seems that this is exactly what you're trying to prove.

**Edit:** For simplicity let's write $A_1=k[x]$ and $A_2=k[y]$. Consider for example the point $(x-y) \in \mathrm{Spec}(k[x,y])$, geometrically this corresponds to the diagonal in the affine plane. When we consider the intersections $(x-y) \cap k[x]$ and $(x-y) \cap k[y]$, we get the zero ideal both times. Geometrically, if you project the diagonal on the $x$-axis or the $y$-axis you get the whole axis. But if we consider instead the zero ideal $(0) \in \mathrm{Spec}(k[x,y])$ (geometrically, the whole affine plane), then you get the same ideals in $k[x]$ and $k[y]$.

Comment: Thank you very much ! But I cannot see why such point in $\mathbb A^2_k$ don't correspond to a point in $|\mathbb A^1_k|\times |\mathbb A^1_k|$.  We have the two projections $Spec A_1\times Spec A_2\to Spec A_1$ and $Spec A_1\times Spec A_2\to Spec A_2$, thus a point in $\mathbb A^2_k$ should give two points in $\mathbb A^1_k$.  Thanks again!

Comment: @WorldLineC204 see my edit

Comment: I meant that you don't get a bijection $|\Bbb A_k^1|\times|\Bbb A_k^1|=\Bbb A^2_k$, which the example shows

Comment: Thank you very much!